# unicornは動いているのに、アプリの画面が表示されない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

「nginx+unicorn+rails5.2.0」で、capistranoを使って、でサーバの構築を行いましたが、nginxの画面しか見えませんでした。一応、ゲストサーバーに入って、unicornの動作を確認しましたが、動いているようです。

> ops@ubuntu-14:/var/www/awesome-events/current$ ps aux | grep unicorn
>   ops       3355  0.0  7.8 266192 80176 ?        Sl   22:05   0:02 unicorn master -c config/unicorn.rb -E none -D                                                   
>   ops       3374  0.0  7.4 267220 75544 ?        Sl   22:05   0:00 unicorn worker[0] -c config/unicorn.rb -E none -D                                                
>   ops       3376  0.0  7.4 267220 75540 ?        Sl   22:05   0:00 unicorn worker[1] -c config/unicorn.rb -E none -D                                                
>   ops       3523  0.0  0.0  11744   924 pts/0    S+   22:56   0:00 grep --color=auto unicorn

そこで、エラーログ（log/unicorn-stderr)の確認を行ったところ、下記のようなメッセージがありました。しかし、どこで、エラーが出ているのか分かりません。どこで、エラーが出ているのか教えて頂けませんでしょうか？また、他にもエラー原因が分かる方法があれば教えて頂けると助かります。（log/unicorn-stdoutでは、何も表示されていませんでした。）

> I, [2018-06-10T22:05:34.389710 #3337]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
>   I, [2018-06-10T22:05:36.394854 #3337]  INFO -- : listening on addr=127.0.0.1:3000 fd=8
>   I, [2018-06-10T22:05:36.399762 #3337]  INFO -- : master process ready
>   I, [2018-06-10T22:05:36.400916 #3341]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
>   I, [2018-06-10T22:05:36.404272 #3344]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
>   I, [2018-06-10T22:05:36.438856 #3355]  INFO -- : executing ["/var/www/awesome-events/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/unicorn", "-c", "config/unicorn.rb", "-E", "none", "-D", {8=>#}] (in /var/www/awesome-events/releases/20180610220523)
>   I, [2018-06-10T22:05:36.439046 #3355]  INFO -- : forked child re-executing...
>   I, [2018-06-10T22:05:36.692161 #3355]  INFO -- : inherited addr=127.0.0.1:3000 fd=8
>   I, [2018-06-10T22:05:36.692392 #3355]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
>   I, [2018-06-10T22:05:38.419510 #3355]  INFO -- : master process ready
>   I, [2018-06-10T22:05:38.422386 #3374]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
>   I, [2018-06-10T22:05:38.425321 #3376]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
>   I, [2018-06-10T22:05:38.518200 #3337]  INFO -- : reaped # worker=0
>   I, [2018-06-10T22:05:38.518296 #3337]  INFO -- : reaped # worker=1
>   I, [2018-06-10T22:05:38.518337 #3337]  INFO -- : master complete

大雑把に言うと、以下のとおり構築しました。
（コードは、必要でしたでしょうか？ファイルが大量ににありすぎるので。。。とりあえず、この様な感じで構築しています。）
⑴「vagrant」でboxをアップし、「chef」でサーバーの構成を行う。
　この時、オペレータユーザを作成して、nodeとしてサーバー情報を追加しまし、プロビジョニングしました。もちろん、nginxのレシピもセットしました。
⑵railsアプリにunicornを追加し、staging環境をセットしました。
　※「RAILS_ENV=staging rake db:setup」⇨「rails s -e staging」を実行したところ、staging環境の画面がブラウザに立ち上がりました。
⑶capistranoを下記のとおり設定し、デプロイしました。
　github経由でアプリファイルを仮想サーバに移し、railsに必要な処理を走らせたのち、unicornを再起動するように設定してしました。
⑷「localhost:8080」をブラウザに入力したところ、nginxの画面しか確認出来ません。
　　※vagrantfileで、「config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host:8080」とした。

ちなみに、nginxの画面は確認できるし、エラーログを見たところ、unicornとnginxもつながっている？？ようにみえるので、以下の点が気になっていますが、どこを確認すればいいのか分からない状態です。
　　①画面への出力が逆になっている。（エラーでないログが、stderr_logに表示されるため）
　　②unicornとrailsの接続がうまく行っていない。または、railsが動いていない？
　　　（正直、unicornとrailsがどのように関わっているのか理解していない。ただ、unicorn．rbファイルをconfigフォルダの下にいれてあればつながると思っています。）

nginx_setting.rb(site-cookbooksのtemplates)
⇨/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
※node["rails_book_cookbook"]["server_name"]=vagrant.local

```
server {
  listen 80; 
  server_name node["rails_book_cookbook"]["server_name"];
  access_log /var/log/nginx/node["rails_book_cookbook"]["server_name"].access.log;
  root /var/www/awesome-events/current/public;
  location / { 
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
   if (!-f $request_filename) {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
     break;
    }   
  }
}
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  charset_types text/css text/plain text/vnd.wap.wml application/javascript application/json application/rss+xml application/xml;
  access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_requests 100;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  gzip  on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_vary off;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml text/javascript application/javascript application/json text/mathml;
  gzip_min_length  1000;
  gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  variables_hash_max_size 1024;
  variables_hash_bucket_size 64;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  types_hash_bucket_size 64;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**conf.d/default.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
   error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

**sites-available/default**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name vagrant.local;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/vagrant.local.access.log;
  location / {
    root /var/www/awesome-events/current/public;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
   if (!-f $request_filename) {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
     break;
    }
  }
}
```

**「ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-available/default」の結果**

> ops@ubuntu-14:~$ ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
>   total 8
>   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 28 09:16 .
>   drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jun 30 03:36 ..
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Jun 28 09:16 000-default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

**awesome-events/current/public」確認結果**

> ps@ubuntu-14:~$ ls -l /var/www/awesome-events/current
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 ops ops 47 Jul  1 03:56 /var/www/awesome-events/current -> /var/www/awesome-events/releases/20180701035403
>   ops@ubuntu-14:~$ ls -l /var/www/awesome-events/current/public
>   total 16
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 ops ops 1722 Jun 26 11:07 404.html
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 ops ops 1705 Jun 26 11:07 422.html
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 ops ops 1635 Jun 26 11:07 500.html
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 ops ops    0 Jun 26 11:07 apple-touch-icon.png
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 ops ops    0 Jun 26 11:07 apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 ops ops   44 Jul  1 03:54 assets -> /var/www/awesome-events/shared/public/assets
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 ops ops    0 Jun 26 11:07 favicon.ico
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 ops ops   98 Jun 26 11:07 robots.txt

**/var/log/nginx/vagrant.local.access.log**

> 10.0.2.2 - - [01/Jul/2018:03:59:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1 Safari/605.1.15"

**sites-available/defaultの修正（tyr_filesディレクティブ）**

> server {
>     listen 80;
>     server_name vagrant.local;
>     access_log /var/log/nginx/vagrant.local.access.log;
>     root /var/www/awesome-events/current/public;
>     location / {
>       try_files $uri $uri/ @app;
>     }
>     location @app {
>       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
>       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
>       proxy_redirect off;
>       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
>     }
>   }

Comment: どのように構築したか書くことはできますか？エラーログと書かれてますが、「INFO」レベルのメッセージなので異常はなさそうにも見えます。

Comment: サーバーの構築からデプロイした状況を追記しました。デプロイ完了後、リモートサーバーにあるrailsの立ち上げになにか必要なコマンド入力があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。ただ、残念ながらはっきりしたことはわかりませんでした。nginx.conf を提示してもらえますか？ Include しているファイルがあればそちらもお願いします。Nginxの画面が表示されるのは、Nginx上のデフォルトサーバーが動いているからだと思います。Railsアプリが表示されないのは、Nginxの設定がうまくできていないか、ホストベースのバーチャルホストの設定が意図したものと違っているためではないかと推測してます。

Comment: unicorn.confを追記します。だんだんと分かってきました。どうやら、chefリポジトリ内のcookbooksにberksfileからダウンロードしたnginxがあり、site-cookbooks内に自分であるnginxを作成したしていました。このnginxがwebアプリに接続する設定のnginxで、こちらのnginxが動いていないようです。unicorn.conf.erbの内容は、現在、勉強中です。どこか間違いがあれば、ご指摘お願いします。

Comment: `listen 80; ` → `listen 80 default_server; ` に変更するとどうでしょうか？こうすると、unicorn.confで定義しているバーチャルホストがデフォルトサーバーになります。

Comment: default_server加えましたけど、ダメでした。。「chef supermarket」からダウンロードしたnginxのコードが難解で、なかなか、苦戦しています。トホホ。

Comment: 何だか、unicorn.confの呼び出しがうまくいってないように思ってきました。それが、どこで行うのか、分からないです。（capistranoのところなのか？それとも、サーバー設定時のところなのか？）

Comment: Chefのコードは一旦置いておいて、/etc/nginx の下の設定ファイルをきちんと把握されたほうが 解決が近いのかなと思います。どんなバーチャルホストが設定してあり、デフォルトサーバーが何なのか、unicorn.conf が読み込まれない（Includeされてない）のはなぜか、を突き止めてから、Chefのコードに取り掛かったほうが良いと思います。

Comment: ご無沙汰しています。ご助言、無視して、ネットワークやchefやら、さまよっていました。（汗。。）デフォルトサーバーが何なのか、確かめる方法を教えて頂けませんか？⇦どうも、nginx.confの「/etc/nginx/sites-enabled」のincludeがうまく行っていないか、別のサーバーにアクセスしている様な気がします。（nginx.confとincludeファイルをアップしました。ちなみに、sites-enableとsites-availableの関係は、「ls /etc/nginx/sites-enable」の結果のとおりです。）それと、リモートサーバー内で、「ping 127.0.0.1」と「curl loclahost:3000」を実行したところ、どちらも、問題なく動いています。

Comment: `unicorn.conf` に `nod.` と書いてありますが、何でしょうか? 質問にコピペする時のミスですか?

Comment: すみません。chefのデータをちょっとイジったら、間違ったりしてました。「unicorn.conf⇨nginx.confのtemplates」で「nod.→node」の間違いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"conf.d/default.conf" で定義された server と、"sites-available/default" で定義さた server がどちらも、80番ポートでリッスンされていることが問題ではないでしょうか?

試しに、"conf.d/default.conf" のリッスンポートを 8080 とかに変更し、 nginx を再起動すれば、 "sites-available/default" の server に 80番ポートでアクセスできるようになるのではないでしょうか?

Comment: ダメでした。「403 Forbidden」エラーが発生します。

Comment: 403なので、切り分けができるかもしれませんよ。まずは、アクセスログ(/var/log/nginx/vagrant.local.access.log)を確認し、意図どおりに、vagrant.local側のサーバーにアクセスがきていることを確かめる。次に、サーバー定義にerror_logを追加して、403の理由がエラーログに出力されないか確かめる。といった具合です。

Comment: 「vagrant.local.log」にアクセスログはありませんでした。ちなみに、/var/log/nginx/error.logをみると、「2018/07/01 02:44:07 [error] 9962#9962: *2 directory index of "/var/www/awesome-events/current/public/" is forbidden, client: 10.0.2.2, server: vagrant.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"」とあります。「client:10.0.2.2」と「directory index of〜」が気になっています。webサーバーを作っているのに、index??ってどういう事？

Comment: エラーメッセージの通りで、"/var/www/awesome-events/current/public/"が存在するかまず確認してください。存在する場合は、nginxを実行しているユーザー(ops)またはグループに該当ディレクトリのアクセス権限があるか確認してください。

Comment: 「awesome-events/current/public」は、追記の「awesome-events/current/public」確認結果のとおり、「シンボリックリンクがはられていますが、アクセス可能です。シンボリックリンクだから、NGとかないですよね？？　それと、nginxは、if文を極力使わない方が良いみたいだったので、try_filesディレクティブを使用（追記）したところ、「/var/log/nginx/vagrant.local.log」に追記の様なlogが認められました。

Comment: そもそも、ローカルサーバーにwebアプリをおいて、"localhost:3000"の実効って、どこにアクセスしにいっているのでしょうか？assets？？あれ、レモーとサーバーでは、unicornではなかったのか？

Comment: nginxの設定にあまり詳しくないのですが、"try_files $uri $uri/ @app;"を"try_files $uri @app;"に変更するとどうなるでしょうか? "$url/"があると rootディレクトリ自体にアクセスするとになり、ディレクトリは存在するため、ディレクトリ自身を表示しようとするけれども"autoindex"が有効になってないため forbidden になっているのかと思いました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。「$uri/」削除すると、動きました。まだまだ、動きを理解していなかったみたいです。汗。。ネットワーク系なんて、さっぱりだったので。。。でも、今回の件で、ようやく、入口に入った気がします。

Comment: お疲れ様でした。時間があるときに、結果の追記および質問にクローズしておくと、他の人の役に立つかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございました。もう少し試してみたいことがあるので。。。うまくいったら、追記してみます。時間があればですが・・・。「クローズ」って、何ですか？

Comment: 回答に緑のチェックを付けることだと思います。(自分で自己解決の回答を作成もできるみたいです。) 同様の疑問を持つ人が検索したときに、解決済みかどうかすぐに判断できるため、回答に辿りつきやすくなります。

Comment: nginxの場合、複数のバーチャルサーバの優先順位が①⇨③の様になっているそうだ。「①listenディレクティブのアドレスとポートに一致するバーチャルサーバを検索する。②リクエストのHostヘッダがserver_nameディレクティブで推定したホストに一致したバーチャルサーバにリクエストを振り分ける。③どのサーバーにも一致しない場合、デフォルトサーバーにリクエストを振りわける」ってな訳で、”sites-available/defaultのlistenを「listen 80 default_server」"に修正し、ブラウザから「127.0.0.1:80801」でアクセスしたら、上手くいった。（今まで、localhost:8080でアクセスしていたので、ダメだったみたい。）バーチャルサーバのIPがローカルホスト同じなので、変なことになっていた。（この辺り。つまり、IPについては、ただいま勉強中で詳しくない。）教えて頂いた「webクライアント側でvagrant.localに対する名前解決の方法は、よく分からなかったですが、この状況だと、無理っぽい気がします。とにかく、IP関連の設定とか勉強しないとです。。。（泣）

Answer (score 0):

`sites-available/default` が次になるように Chef の方を修正してみてください。`default_server` オプションをつけることで明示的に `sites-available/default` の方をデフォルトにしています。

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name vagrant.local;
       ::::
```

もしくは、`nginx.conf` で `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` の行をコメントアウトすれば、`conf.d/default.conf` の内容が無視されるので、結果的に `site-available/default` の内容がデフォルトになると思います。（他にもファイルがある場合は、話が変わってしまうので 先述の方法のがおすすめです。）

もう一つの回避方法は、Webクライアント側の PC?で `vagrant.local` に対する名前解決が出来るようにしてください。具体的には hosts ファイルに次の行を追加します。

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   vagrant.local
```

※「xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx」はサーバーのIPアドレス

こうすると、`sites-available/default` の方のバーチャルサーバーが応答を返すと思います。